# Validating parameters in OS Kernel

Tags: operating-system, kernel

The user mode calls a function with virtual address and size parameters , if we validating the parameters in two cases
1-Not pointing to NULL
2-Not pointing to invalid pointer (pointing to unmapped memory)
which goes as in kern:

```
 case SYS_free_user_mem:
//        here should the validation?
         if((uint32)a1 == NULL && (uint32)a2 == NULL)
        {
            sched_kill_env(curenv->env_id);
        }
         else if ((uint32)a1 == ? && (uint32)a2 == ?){
                        sched_kill_env(curenv->env_id);
         }
            sys_free_user_mem((uint32)a1,(uint32)a2);
            return 0;
            break;
```

What is the right condition to validate it is not pointing to unmapped memory?

I searched for solutions like making a struct called mem_map has two members [start , end]

// An array to store the memory mappings of the current process
struct Mem_Mapping process_mem_mapping[max_mapping];

and define the numOfMapping to define the number of mappings in the array
int numOfMapping = 0;

```
// Function to check if a memory region is mapped in the current process
bool is_user_memory_mapped((uint32) virtual_address, uint32 size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numMappings; i++) {
        if (virtual_address >= process_mem_mapping[i].start && 
            virtual_address + size <= process_mem_mapping[i].end) {
            return true; // The memory region is mapped
        }
    }
    return false; // The memory region is not mapped
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It is up to you how to validate addresses in your own kernel. Yes, you could do that by testing address against all memory regions which are mapped. That way could be optimized by having sorted array of memory regions: in that case you could use binary search when validate the address.